# (Laravel) only retrieving users that have a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

In my site I have users and items. Users can create items. I want to get an array that has all users, where the users which have an item go first and the users which do not have an item go after.

So far I have done this:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user) {
    if ($user->item) {
        $sortedUsers + $user;
    }
// now loop again and add users without relationship
```

This is pretty inefficient and I'm sure there's a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query on the existence of a relationship

```
$users = User::has('items')->with('items')->get();
```

with that syntax you are telling laravel to fetch all users that have a item and to eager load the items;

Edit: 
After reading it does not look like you actually want the items just the users that have a item in that case all you need is

```
$users = User::has('items')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the relation of `Items` to `Users` I'm not sure if this will work but you can try the following:

```
$users = Users::select('users.*')->orderBy('items.id')->with('items')->get();
```

Or it might work with just:

```
$users = Users::orderBy('items.id')->with('items')->get();
```

**Update**

```
$users = Users::orderBy('items.id')->join('items', 'items.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->get();
```

Comment: the user does not have an item.id column. user has many items, item has one user. Item has user.id column though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

> $users = User::with('item')->get();
>
> foreach ($users as $user) {
>
> ```
> echo $User->item->name;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to get users with items and [`doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) to get users without items:

```
$withItems = User::has('items')->get();

$withoutItems = User::doesntHave('items')->get();
```

And then [`merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-merge) two collections:

```
$users = $withItems->merge($withoutItems);
```

You said you want an array, so you can convert result into an array with [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-toarray)

```
$array = $users->toArray();
```